# Why isn't this infinite recursion? 

Tags: python, function, recursion

I would like to ask you about a code in Python:

```
class UserDict:
    def __init__(self, dict=None, **kwargs):
        self.data = {}
        if dict is not None:
            self.update(dict)
        if len(kwargs):
            self.update(kwargs)
    def clear(self): self.data.clear()
```

Here, `clear(self)` is a method of `UserDict` class, and operates on class's `data` attribute,  right? Won't this function operate on `data` forever? Because it calls itself every time?

Answer (score 6):

`UserDict.clear()` calls `self.data.clear()`.  `self.data` is of type `dict`, not `UserDict`, so it calls a different method, not itself.  It would be an infinite recursion if `UserDict.clear()` called `self.clear()` instead of `self.data.clear()`.

Answer (score 2):

No, This method calls the `clear` method of the `data` dict, which is totally unrelated to `UserDict`.